# PHP random reorder of elements

Tags: php, random

I am trying to randomise the order of a series of elements for a websites homepage.

Imagine we have 3 titles to display on this page.

```
$title1 = 'the first title';
$title2 = 'the second title';
$title3 = 'the third title';
```

Now on the HTML file we want to display these but in a random order and never repeating one element.

```
<html>
<div id='titleholder1'> [ randomly show either $title1, $title2 or $title3 ] </div>
<div id='titleholder2'> [ randomly show either $title1, $title2 or $title3 ] </div>
<div id='titleholder3'> [ randomly show either $title1, $title2 or $title3 ] </div>

</html>
```

Also it must avoid ever repeating `$title1 $title2 or $title 3` on the page.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

EDIT.

What would we need to do if we had more than one element.

```
$title1 = 'the first title';    $info1 = 'the first info';
    $title2 = 'the second title';     $info2 = 'the second info';
    $title3 = 'the third title';    $info3 = 'the third info';
```

Same principle but obviously `$info1` and `$title1` need to stay together and be shuffled together.

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text into an `array` and `shuffle` it.

```
<?php
$titles[] = 'one';
$titles[] = 'two';
$titles[] = 'three';

shuffle($titles);
?>

<div class="titleholder1"><?php echo $titles[0];?></div>
<div class="titleholder2"><?php echo $titles[1];?></div>
<div class="titleholder3"><?php echo $titles[2];?></div>
```

[php.net/shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle)

---

Update

```
$webpage[] = array('info' => 'first info', 'title' => 'first title');
$webpage[] = array('info' => 'second info', 'title' => 'second title');
$webpage[] = array('info' => 'thrid info', 'title' => 'third title');
```

Comment: I have updated my question as although that solved the example. We beed ti know what to do with additional elements

Comment: Only 2 up votes? Either there's a dupe, or something is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Put them into an array and shuffle it using [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle):

```
$titles = array($title1, $title2, $title3);
shuffle($titles);
foreach ($titles as $i => $title) {
    echo '<div id="titleholder'.($i+1).'">'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Ummm... array_shuffle?  Really?

Comment: @awm: Fixed it; it’s just `shuffle`.

Comment: Cheers. :) And +1 for pointing out the obvious need for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the strings to an array and then call [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function which randomly shuffles the array.